# Python requests..compat.urljoin - prepend an access method when URL does not contain one

Tags: python, https, python-requests

Here are two ways I'm trying to prepend the `https://` to a URL.  For some reason the urljoin method gives strange output:

```
from requests.compat import urljoin

host = 'abc.def.com'
host2 = host

# brute-force string method
if not host.startswith('https://'):
    host = 'https://' + host  # Add schema
if host.endswith('/'):
    host = host[:-1]          # Strip /
print('Stringy way', host)

# nice library method? Doesn't quite work
print('urljoin    ', urljoin('https://', host2))
```

The output I see, with the weird three /// characters, are

```
Stringy way https://abc.def.com
urljoin     https:///abc.def.com
```

I get non-useful results with other variants too:

```
print('urljoin #2 ', urljoin('https:/', host2))
print('urljoin #3 ', urljoin('https:', host2))
print('urljoin #4 ', urljoin('https', host2))
```

gives:

```
urljoin #2  https:///abc.def.com
urljoin #3  https:///abc.def.com
urljoin #4  abc.def.com
```

Is this the wrong function to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can utilize [`urllib.parse.urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit) to compose URLs:

```
from urllib.parse import urlunsplit

print(urlunsplit(("https", "abc.def.com", "", "", "")))
```

Result:

```
https://abc.def.com
```

It takes a tuple as input that matches the output of [`urlsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit), with the following attributes of the tuple:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The urljoin function is generally used for attaching an href anchor to the existing url. Example:

```
from requests.compat import urljoin
url = 'https://abc.def.com'
href = '364'
urljoin(url, href)
```

I get the output:-

```
'https://abc.def.com/364'
```

However if I want to complete my url with 'https://' I would rather use:-

```
from requests.compat import urljoin
url = 'abc.def.com'
host = ('https://'+ url)
print(host)
```

And the output I have is:

```
https://abc.def.com
```

I hope this helped.

Comment: I think this is the "brute force string method" I showed in the example.